# How to calculate flux of vector field

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, divergence-operator

A vector field is given as $A = (yz, xz, xy)$ through surface $x+y+z=1$ where $x,y,z \ge 0$, normal is chosen to be $\hat{n} \cdot e_z > 0$. Calculate the flux of the vector field.

I tried using Gauss theorem $ \iint_S A \cdot \hat{n}dS = \iiint_D \nabla \cdot A dV $, but $\nabla \cdot A $ gave the result of $0$, so I'm unsure how to tackle this problem. Any clues are welcome!

Comment: take the divergence of the function

Comment: Gauss' theorem can only be used over closed surfaces.  That doesn't mean that you can't use it, but if you do, you will need to find the flux across the surfaces that close up the volume.

Comment: You can calculate the flux passing through the surface.

Comment: If you're going to use divergence, you'd best compute it correctly. It's a scalar function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating it directly

$z = 1 - x- y\\
dS = (1,1,1)$

$\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} (y(1-x-y),x(1-x-y), xy)\cdot(1,1,1) \ dx\ dy$

$\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} x+y - xy - x^2 - y^2 \ dx\ dy\\
\int_0^1  (x-x^2)(1-x)+ (1-x)(\frac 12 (1-x)^2) - \frac 13 (1-x)^3\ dy\\
\int_0^1  x(1-x)^2+ \frac 16 (1-x)^3\ dy\\
\int_0^1 (1-x)^2- \frac 56 (1-x)^3\ dy\\
\frac 13 - \frac 5{24} = \frac 18$

As you suggested using the divergence theorem.

We can create a tetrahedron 3 triangles in the xy,yz, xz planes.

$\iint f(x,y,z) \ dA_1 + \iint f(x,y,z) \ dA_2 + \iint f(x,y,z) \ dA_3 + \iint f(x,y,z) \ dS = \iint \nabla \cdot f dV$

$\nabla \cdot f = 0$

and by the symmetry of the figure.

$\iint f(x,y,z) \ dA_1 = \iint f(x,y,z) \ dA_2 = \iint f(x,y,z) \ dA_3$

$\iint f(x,y,z) \ dS = -3 \iint f(x,y,z) \ dA_1$

We need our normals pointed outward. $(0,0,-1)$ would be the be the suitable normal

$\iint f(x,y,z) \ dS =  3\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} xy\ dx\ dy$

Comment: Ah ok, I also tried to calculate directly. The mistake I had was for both integrals, I had both of them go from 0 to 1!